# Laravel 5.3 : hidden fields are returned in JSON response

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

First of all I've searched the web for an answer and could not find any which quite astonished me. Maybe I did not search for the right terms, please excuse me in advance if this is the case.

So I defined in my model some fields as hidden :

```
protected $hidden = [
    'hasExpired', 'hasBeenTreated', 'reporterId'
];
```

And this is how I output the results :

```
return response()->json([
         'latestReports' => $latestReports
       ]);
```

And the $latestReports variable is defined somewhere else as :

```
$query = DB::table('reports')
            ->where('catId', 0) ;

$latestReports = $query->where('hasExpired', 0)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->get();
```

How on earth is it possible that these fields still appear in the response I get on the client from the server, and above all what should I correct to prevent them from appearing. In other word how can I make the hidden array be enforced ?

Please note: for some other models (e.g. users) the hidden array is enforced, that is the hidden fields do not appear in the response.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: How do you create the $query object?

Comment: Hi Jedrzej.Kurylo, please see my edits ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason hidden fields are shown is that you fetch data from the database table directly using **DB::table()** instead of using your model. **$hidden** array is used when serialising Eloquent models to JSON and you're bypassing the Eloquent layer this way so the query has no way of knowing that some columns should be hidden.

Replace

```
$query = DB::table('reports')->where('catId', 0);
```

with

```
$query = Report::where('catId', 0);
```

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks a lot Jedrzej.Kurylo!